# replace column of a csv file with column from another file

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, perl, csv

I have two sample files like this:

```
$ cat file1
abc,sachin
cat,kumar 

$ cat file2
xyz
pressure

$ cat file3 
xyz,sachin
pressure, kumar
```

I want the first column of `file1` to be replaced with `file2`.

I tried doing something like this:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$3;next}{$2=a[FNR]}1' file1 file2
```

I'm using Solaris 10 and it didn't appear to support this. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

How about using `cut` and `paste`? if your shell supports process substitutions, then

```
$ paste -d, file2.txt <(cut -d, -f2 file1.txt)
xyz,sachin
pressure,kumar
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the input field separator.  Moreover, I'm not sure how you are choosing the fields.  In awk, the fields are 1-based.  You don't have 3 fields in either of the input files.

The following should work for you:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{$1=a[FNR]}1' OFS=, file2.txt file1.txt
```

For your sample input, it'd produce:

```
xyz,sachin
pressure,kumar
```

Comment: It gives me an Error like this, thats why i asked an suggestion for some other answer . 
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @praveen Not sure what's causing the error.  Could you try `awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{$1=a[FNR]}1' file2.txt file1.txt` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should try @devnull's answer with `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `nawk`.

Many of the programs under `/usr/bin` and `/bin` on `Solaris` are not `POSIX` compatible.

Or you can use `perl` for portable:

```
$ perl -nle '                  
    unless (/,/) {                  
        push @a, $_;       
        next;
    }
    @l = split ",", $_;
    print "$a[$i++],$l[1]";
' file2.txt file1.txt
xyz,sachin
pressure,kumar
```

Even shorter:

```
$ perl -F',' -anle '
    if (@F == 1) {push @a,$_;next}    
    print "$a[$i++],$F[1]";
' file2.txt file1.txt
```